# How to extract all the links given a html file and even the file size?

Tags: javascript, java, html, rss-reader

Is it possible to list all the links that exist in the html page, given the html link as an input, pretty much you see it here?
http://www.feedbucket.com/?src=http://allearsenglish.libsyn.com/rss&start=0

It looks like the website reads all the links that exist and give me the summary, and reads file size of the mp3 link without opening it.

Do you know any good tutorials that helps me learn this topic or similar topics?

Comment: In Javascript, this cannot be done due to the [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). Simply put: For security reasons it's not possible to get the source code of an external website with Javascript unless that website specificly allows it. You'll have to use a server side language like Java or PHP to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea. You can get all links in these URL by using the split function, like:

```
var link =  "http://www.feedbucket.com/?src=http://allearsenglish.libsyn.com/rss&start=0";
var links = link.split("http://");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java at server side (because of the java tag)

You can use this Java html parser library: [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/)

You would request the page from the input url like this:

```
String src = request.getParameter("src");
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(src).get();
```

and then parse "doc" to find all the links in the page like this:

```
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
```

[Here](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links) is a similar example.

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of HTML parsing libraries out there. [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) is pretty great for Java. You would do something like below to get a list of the elements. And then you'd iterate through the list to print them, get file size, whatever else you wanted to get with them

```
Jsoup.connect("http://www.feedbucket.com/?src=http://allearsenglish.libsyn.com/rss&start=0").get().getElementsByAttribute("href");
```

What the HTML parser libraries will do is get the page source, and grab all the HTML tags, and from there filter for something like a "a" tag for link.